# Model of a specific DVB-T tuner chip (circa 2013) that can be used to collect raw IQ samples

Tags: software-defined-radio

There is a common DVB-T receiver chip capable of producing raw IQ samples, which makes it a good device for Amateur Radio SDR experimentation.

The chips is used in some DVB-T USB dongles sold around 2012-2013. What is the model of that chip and which DVB-T dongles are known to use it?

Comment: Please suggest how to make the question better before downvoting.

Comment: 1) This is very localized and will not be very useful in just a few years time. 2) hardware and product recommendations aren't typically supported on stack exchange sites for a variety of reasons, but there is precedent for sites that support it.  We should discuss it on meta.

Comment: There is just one of these and it is widely available and a much used tool in amateur radio circles.

Comment: Also specific hardware such as RD-58 will be used for decades. I'd suspect this applies to RTL2832U unless there will be better solution which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely referring to the Realtek RTL2832U

A dongle compatibility chart for this chip can be found here:

http://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/wiki/compatibility